# How to add env variable to pytest in vscode for the side bar?

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, pytest

I created launch json for tests in vscode and it works well in terminal, but vscode don't see tests in the side bar, becouse side bar don't get environment variables from launch.json. How to add environment variables for the side bar?

[image]

Comment: In pycharm I can add env variables in pytest configuration, I suppose in vscode must have the same functional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, need to use `pip install pytest-env`

Comment: Hi Piter, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Open vscode without any file and folder.
Go to your folder which is stocking launch.json and drag & drop your folder on VScode. And retry your test

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think your tests not being detected is not because of your environment variables. It is because you have not set your python interpreter in vscode properly.

Comment: python interpreter works well, when I opening a new terminal everything is ok and project running with env variables

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add `"env"` in your `launch.json` to add env variable to pytest.

`launch.json`(just as an example):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: pytest",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "pytest",
            "args": ["-v"], 
            "env": {
                "ENV_VARIABLE_NAME": "value",
                "ANOTHER_ENV_VARIABLE": "another_value"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can [read document for more details](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_env). And you can also set [envFile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_envfile) at the root of the workspace folder.

Comment: as you can see on screenshot above I added env variable in launch.json, and I have two different envs for app and test and they have the same names, but different paths, for example:

python app env: { config_path: value1 }
tests env: env: { config_path: value2 }

the problem that the side bar does not see these env variables